# Tooltip in Standard widgets toolkit

Tags: java, swt, tooltip, mouse-listeners

I need to add an `if` condition before `label.addMouseListener(mouseListener)` in my code only to add the listener if the *tooltip* text is set or if the tooltip text is empty the listener will not be added. So I coded this way:

```
if (tooltip.getText() != null) {
    label.addMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
}
```

But the above only works only if tooltip text is set and displays the tooltip but if the             tooltip text is empty then an empty tooltip shows up which i do not want..

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't know how to format the question because you didn't read the tour. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: try this - `if (tooltip.getText() != null && !tooltip.getText().isEmpty()) {}`

Comment: Show us more code! You could use Label#getTooltipText()